# Naming convention for Web Apps added via the Add to Home Screen on iOS or Android?

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, native, homescreen

I am developing a **Web App** with Rails which I am then adding via the **Add to Home Screen option** (and testing in Simulator via Xcode).

What we call such apps in my workplace is (Home Screen App Mode) **'HSAM'** (in what we see as the absence of any naming convention for this particular scenario).

**What I essentially want to know is, is there a naming convention to describe Web Apps built to such an end**?

Possibilities I have found include:

**- 'Shortcut'

 - 'Non-native'

 - 'Homescreen'

 - 'Add to Home Screen'**

None of the above keywords seem to pinpoint results of what I am looking for when I am attempting to debug issues specific to this format.

**Is there a naming convention? If so, what is the accepted term for these specific apps?**

Comment: It's not an app, its a website :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen), A2HS (which at the time of writing only gives 94 results on StackOverflow

> Add to Home screen (or A2HS for short)

It is referred to as A2HS for the rest of the linked page.